# jeromq: closing context fails

Tags: java, zeromq, jeromq

### EDIT: solved myself, see below (although I'm not sure if I've stumbled upon a bug here)

Using the simple hello-world request-reply example below, closing the context at the end of the program fails: Either it simply hangs at `ctx.close()` or it throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "reaper-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at zmq.Ctx.destroy_socket(Ctx.java:327)
    at zmq.ZObject.destroy_socket(ZObject.java:144)
    at zmq.SocketBase.check_destroy(SocketBase.java:938)
    at zmq.SocketBase.start_reaping(SocketBase.java:753)
    at zmq.Reaper.process_reap(Reaper.java:133)
    at zmq.ZObject.process_command(ZObject.java:114)
    at zmq.Reaper.in_event(Reaper.java:90)
    at zmq.Poller.run(Poller.java:233)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Either way, the program does *not* halt.

Here is the code (please note that the sockets are both closed within the threads that create them):

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;
import org.zeromq.ZContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final ZContext ctx = new ZContext();

        final Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ZMQ.Socket socket = ctx.createSocket(ZMQ.REQ);
                socket.connect("inproc://test");
                System.err.format("[Thread %s] socket connected%n", Thread.currentThread().getId());
                socket.send("hello");
                System.err.format("[Thread %s] hello sent%n", Thread.currentThread().getId());
                String result = socket.recvStr();
                System.err.format("[Thread %s] received response '%s'%n", Thread.currentThread()
                        .getId(), result);
                socket.close();
                System.err.format("[Thread %s] socket closed%n", Thread.currentThread().getId());
                ctx.destroySocket(socket);
                System.err.format("[Thread %s] socket destroyed%n", Thread.currentThread().getId());
            }
        };
//      t1.start();

        final Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ZMQ.Socket socket = ctx.createSocket(ZMQ.REP);
                socket.setLinger(10000);
                socket.bind("inproc://test");
                System.err.format("                    [Thread %s] socket bound%n", Thread.currentThread().getId());
                String request = socket.recvStr();
                assert request == "hello";
                System.err.format("                    [Thread %s] received request '%s'%n", Thread.currentThread()
                        .getId(), request);
                socket.send("world");
                socket.close();
                System.err.format("                    [Thread %s] socket closed%n", Thread.currentThread().getId());
                ctx.destroySocket(socket);
                System.err.format("                    [Thread %s] socket destroyed%n", Thread.currentThread().getId());
            }
        };
        t2.start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        t1.start();

        System.err.println("waiting on the threads to finish...");
        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        System.err.println("closing context...");
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

### EDIT: solved

It turns out that `socket.close()` does not work, and that `ctx.destroySocket(socket)` alone suffices (it also closes the socket). So removing `socket.close()` resolves the issue. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same issue; it's not a bug, use one or the other, not both, but use the `ZContext` methods, they're more efficient.

`close()` explicitly closes the socket, so calling `ctx.destroySocket()` afterwards throws that exception. If you need to close the socket, use `ctx.destroySocket()`, don't use `close()` at all, and always use `ctx.destroy()` to close the context before shutting down and exiting gracefully, it will automatically close any sockets created from that context.

Answer (score 3):

I also had a similar problem, and after some surfing I found a discussion about related topics on JeroMQ (java implementation of ZMQ)'s Github site.

https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/issues/40

It would seem that ZMQ.Context is part of a low level API, while ZContext is a higher level API. Consequently, context.close should not be used with ZContext, while ctx.destroySocket() should. And I'm sure there are a host of other similar issues one should know about.